# Confusion on how info is stored in my dictionary and how to look it up

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a dictionary of 300 rows of data that were read from a spreadsheet. Here is dictionary_list[1]:

```
 {'_chk2m': 'Name1@domain.com', '_cn6ca': 'PaulDu', '_cokwr': '005C0000003yL', '_ckd7g': 'Sourcing', '_cre1l': u'Paul Dumond \xa0', '_cpzh4': 'Name1@domain.com', '_ciyn3': 'abc'}
```

I thought the I could print 'Name1@domain.com' by calling the key '_chk2m'like this:

```
print dictionary_list['_chk2m']
```

but got the error: "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str"

So this is a list and not a dictionary? Or a list of lists? (sorry, I'm a new python user)

My overall goal is to have the user input (raw_input) the name and have the email returned. Basically, I am trying to automatically look up someone's email based on a user input of their name, then keep/save this email to enter into a csv. Any suggestions on how I might do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dictionary_list` is a `list`, as you have stated already, so this should work

```
print dictionary_list[1]['_chk2m']
```

Comment: That worked. Is there any way that I can ask for a user input, locate the row of data with that input, and extract a different piece of data from that row?

Comment: @gigawatts: no.  At least, not in the comments,  Ask a new question.